# xargs and line-by-line pipe

Tags: xargs

I have 3 files: `a.txt`, `b.txt` and `c.txt`. I want to create 3 files: `a.test`, `b.test` and `c.test` containing the simple text `abracadabra`.

Basicaly, the point is to create the `.test` files for each `.txt` file, and fill them with some text. I am trying to use `xargs` to do this.

```
anlx2626> ls
a.txt  b.txt  c.txt

anlx2626> ls *.txt | awk -F'.txt' '{print $1}' | xargs -I {} echo "abracadabra" > {}.test

anlx2626> ls *.test
ls: No match.
```

Could someone point out why using the `{}` placeholder for
line-by-line pipe doesn't work the way I expect it to?

Answer (score 2):

In this code:

```
xargs -I {} echo "abracadabra" > {}.test
```

xargs will not see the redirection operator `>` at all: it will be
interpreted by your shell instead, creating a file named, literally,
`{}.test`.

One way to do what you ask using xargs is this, which lets sh
interpret the redirection operator:

```
xargs sh -c 'for i do echo abracadrabra > "$i"; done' sh
```

But you would probably be better off not using xargs at all, which other
answers explain how to do.

Comment: What if there's a `$(rm -rf "$HOME").txt` file in the current directory?

Comment: Then Bad Things would happen. I added a note to that effect.

Comment: Then make it `xargs sh -c 'for i do echo abracadrabra > "$i"; done' sh`

Comment: I tried to answer the explicit question, that asks why the redirect doesn't seem to work. I fully agree that your answer is a much better approach to actually creating `.test` files. I'm not sure what your point is: do you mean it would be better if I omitted my attempt at fitting a solution within `xargs`' constraints?

Comment: I mean that you shoud not embed the {} in the shell code, pass it as an argument to `sh`. You could also make it `xargs -I{} sh -c 'echo abracadabra > "$1"' sh {}` which wouldn't have tha code injection vulnerability but would run one sh per file.

Comment: Ah, good point. I will integrate your code into my answer, then.

Answer (score 2):

`awk` can output text, not need for `echo` or `xargs`. Your approach has issues for file names with more than one dot, like `foo-1.2.txt`.

It would also have issues for filenames with newlines in them or if there are directories whose name ends in `.txt`.

For once, I'd use a loop here, for instance with zsh:

```
(set -o noclobber; for f (*.txt(N)) echo abracadabra > $f:r.test)
```

Or POSIXly:

```
(set -o noclobber
 for f in *.txt; do
   echo abracadabra > "${f%.*}.test"
 done)
```

The `noclobber` is to avoid overriding an already existing file. Note that it omits hidden files. If there's no `txt` file, the POSIX sh variant will create a `*.test` file.

Answer (score 0):

Although this has been answered adequately, I'm just adding this to show another way:

```
while IFS= read -r
do
echo abracadabra > "${REPLY}.test"
done < <(find . -maxdepth 1 -name "*.txt" -exec basename -s .txt {} \;)
```

Here find is used to list the text files. `maxdepth` is used to stop find from recursing into child folders. `basename -s .txt` is being used to remove the txt extension right at the start because except to list the names we don't need it at all.
In the while loop, we simply use the name without the extension, and use string substitution to add the `.test` extension, while echoing to the file. Note that we have used the default variable of `while`, which is `$REPLY`.

Comment: Welcome to the site, and thank you for your contribution. Please note however that this will not work if the filenames contain newlines (which is rare, but permitted). See [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/321697/377345) for a discussion on this.

Comment: It also runs one `basename` command (with the non standard `-s` option) for each file which is rather inefficient and assumes a Korn-like shell for `read` defaulting to `read REPLY` and process substitution

Comment: I was under the impression that IFS= implies null character as ending and so newlines would be taken care of. Is it that a -print0 needs to be explicitly stated? Also, I see the point that running basename every time may be inefficient. But this does work for me in git bash.

Answer (score -2):

```
for l in $(ls *.txt); do echo "abrakadabra" > $l; done
```

Comment: Hello nepsse. Why are you parsing `ls` instead of just using `for l in *.txt`? What's `$1` intended to be? Generally here we prefer code to be explained rather than just dumped into an answer.

Comment: It also doesn't address the question in the Question.

Comment: This overwrites the original txt files